# Инъекция JavaScript-кода, который продолжит работать после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, бот

Теория:

JavaScript-код, запускаемый в Firebug или консоли Chrome, работает до перезагрузки страницы. Но для реализации некоторых задач необходима перезагрузка.

Как сделать JavaScript-скрипт, который будет делать что-то на странице, потом "переживёт" перезагрузку страницы и продолжит выполняться: через некоторое время сможет опять всё это повторить, и так бесконечное число раз вышеописанными средствами?

---

Сама проблема достаточно земная. Если кто-то из Вас встречал bitcoin-кранчики, то он меня поймёт. Есть сайт, где кранчики сделаны просто для тысячи разных монет, - вот я там.

Хочу сделать такую JavaScript-давилку-на-кнопки. Проблема в том, что кран даёт монетки лишь раз в час.

Каждый раз надо обновлять страничку, и больше 10 монеток собрать нельзя.

Сам маленький скрипт я напишу, он будет 10 монеток кликать, но вот как это автоматизировать так, чтобы раз в час он обновлялся, и мне не приходилось заново открывать консоль и выполнять скрипт?

Comment: Возможно, получится такое сделать, написав плагин для браузера. Если не получится, всегда можно взять что-то вроде http://www.awesomium.com, чтобы грузить какие угодно страницы когда  вам угодно, вставляя какие угодно скрипты на страницу.

Comment: Можно использовать user js, который запускается при открытии страница автоматически и добавить в него reload.

Comment: @Alex-Krass, при открытии не комильфо, надо что бы страничка была открыта всё время. Кранчик раз в час даёт 10 монеток разных, раз в день всё это заново обновляется. Можно конечно всё хранить, и просто пост-запросами долбить в определённые промежутки времени, но возник вопрос, а как вообще такое делается на javascript? Неужели без плагинов ни как? Неужели средств chrome или FireBug-а недостаточно, и перезагрузка страницы - это как конец света....

Comment: Firebug был придуман не для того, чтобы монеты из крана собирать.

Comment: @decyrus, посмотри, изменил, убирай минусинск свой

Comment: В вопросе у Вас указано условие "каждый раз надо обновлять страничку", а теперь вы говорите, что переоткрывать ее не надо? Или Вы меня не так понимаете, или в условиях своих же путаетесь. Я предложил вариант, написать свой собственный плагин с нуля, который это и будет делать.

Comment: @Alex-Krass, я же описал саму проблему, 1 раз в час - 10 монет можно кликнуть, раз в день можно каждую покликать, всего монет 1000. Т.е. каждый час надо обновляться и перезапускаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, что бы сделать бота на странице который сам бы производил какие-то действия, перезагружал страницу и продолжал работу после обновления страницы, можно использовать пользовательские расширения для браузеров(они же пользовательские скрипты, userscript js, user js).

Для примитивнейшего примера возьмем пользовательское расширение для chrome: 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Создается простая папка которая называется произвольно по имени расширения, в которой пишется манифест файл и скрипт, который будет выполнятся.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My Extension",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://www.yandex.ru/"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.yandex.ru/"],
      "js": ["bg.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

**bg.js**

```
console.log("timestamp :"+new Date());
window.setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 10000)
```

Заметьте, в коде скрипта находится Timeout с перезагрузкой страницы reload(). Данный код по прошествии времени перезагрузит страницу и автоматически снова запустит сам себя без вашего участия.

Для правильного составления манифеста, стоит обратиться к документации.

Далее стоит просто добавить этот скрипт в расширения:

1. перейти в chrome->расширения
2. отметить галочку "режим разработчика"
3. выбрать "загрузить распакованное расширение" и указать папку с нашим кодом

После этого расширение должно работать. В данном случае оно при первом ручном открытии яндекса выводит в консоль текущую дату и после 10 секунд ожидания перезагружает страницу и продолжает работу по кругу уже без вашего участия.

Comment: выглядит чудесно, попробуем, спасип...

Comment: Работает! Я раньше и не подозревал что написание расширений - это такое простое занятие. Благодарствую. Аплодисменты.